# Subscripts as variable in plot label

Tags: r, text, plot, label, subscript

I have n plots with subscript label. Defined labels:

```
lab<-c("NO[2]","NO","CO[2]","CO")
lab2<-noquote(lab)
plot(1,1,xlab=bquote(.(lab[1])))
plot(1,1,xlab=bquote(.(lab2[1])))
```

I want this but with .variable

```
plot(1,1,xlab=bquote(NO[2]))
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `parse` the string.

```
plot(1, 1, xlab = bquote(.(parse(text = lab[1]))))
```

[image]